# Having an image (without container) not stretched

Tags: html, css

I would like my image to be not stretched and no scroll bars. So when the browser window is reduced the image is still the same size (but overflow is hidden).

```
<img src="http://nybbledesigns.com/images/header.jpg"/>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ppL9axc/

I found solutions with containers but I need a solution without.

Any idea?

Comment: You can put the overflow on the body, but I don't think that's wishful. Or you could set the image as background of the body. Otherwise I think you are stuck to the container solution.

Comment: I prefer keeping my image in the img tag

Comment: As far as I know you'll need an wrapper element.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```css
img {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://nybbledesigns.com/images/header.jpg"/>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the image is fixed then when I scroll down, the image is not scrolling with the page...

Comment: @Bronzato I know but that requirement wasn't in the question tough ;P

Answer (score 0):

I made a background version, hope it could help.

```
<div></div>
div {
width:100%;height:60vh;
background-image:url("http://nybbledesigns.com/images/header.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

}

The vh is relative to the device screen height so 60vh will be 60% relative to the screen height
at all time, no matter which device :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It will disable the scroll bars forever~

Answer (score 0):

try this 
`img {max-width:100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the new CSS property `object-fit` ([Currently webkit only, but soon to be supported in other browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

Just set `object-fit: cover;` on the `img` together width a max-width and fixed height.

This is basically the equivalent to to applying `background-size:cover` to a background image , except that here we apply it to an `img` element.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6ppL9axc/1/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 513px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://nybbledesigns.com/images/header.jpg" />
```